# 1T USB drive will not accept ext4 or xfs filessystem

Tags: ext4, usb-drive, xfs

I bought two 1T USB drives that I wanted to use for a backup media. They came default with exFAT on them and I can mount them with fuse drivers on Centos. But I would rather use a native filesystem like ext4 or xfs because I am only going to use them on my Centos boxes and I want to keep user and permission.

They both format fine and can be used on a Windows machine, and I can mount them using the fuse driver in Centos so I know they work.

First I fdisk one and delete/create a new Linux partition. No errors or warnings, I mkfs.ext4 on it and it formats it with no errors or warnings. But when I try to mount it, mount says it has a bad superblock. I fsck it and there are a bunch of errors and I say `y` to them to get them fixed. Still it will not mount.

I move to a different newer machine and run gparted. I have gparted format to a ext4, again, it formats fine with no errors, but it will not mount saying there is no superblock. So I try xfs. It formats fine, no errors. Still does not mount, says not a valid filesystem.

I stick it in my windows box and re-format it as exfat, it works fine and I can read/write to it.

Any idea why I cannot format them in ext4 or xfs? Is it possible the manufacture has locked what fs type can be used?

fdisk has no issue setting the partitions or the fs type, but after formatting it, the drive becomes unusable unless it's exFAT. Also just to be complete, there are no warnings or errors in dmesg either.

Comment: Just a guess, is it USB 3 ? If so try to connect them with USB 2. Something like this  has happened to  me, and it worked with USB 2.

Comment: Sounds like your flash drive might be a Chinese counterfeit (e.g., a 16GB drive rewritten to claim it's 1TB), and ext4's layout is different enough from exFAT that the controller can't maintain the ruse as long as usual.

Comment: Try running `sudo badblock -sv -w -t random /dev/sdx`.  (IT WILL DESTROY ALL DATA)  If the drive is a counterfeit or severely damaged, it will list a whole lot of errors.